# Select with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, select, driver, scrape

I wish to use Select to click on the 3rd option in the 1st drop-down ("Fejlesztési programok") menu at the following site: https://www.palyazat.gov.hu/tamogatott_projektkereso?fbclid=IwAR3rmPVj-YAVoMTs2Vodj7JKTVIAZkbTiZ9z4b0j04mq2ThECw5kQOI1p7M

I used css-selector to find the menus id, but it is not reacting to the call. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Many thank in advance

The minimalist example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
driver = webdriver.Safari(executable_path = '/usr/bin/safaridriver')

driver.get("https://www.palyazat.gov.hu/tamogatott_projektkereso?fbclid=IwAR3rmPVj-YAVoMTs2Vodj7JKTVIAZkbTiZ9z4b0j04mq2ThECw5kQOI1p7M")

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('css-1uccc91-singleValue'))
select.select_by_index(2)
```

Comment: _This site can’t be reached_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. You should add a delay to try locating the element only when it's accessible.
2. The element you are trying to access is not `select`.
   This should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Safari(executable_path = '/usr/bin/safaridriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.palyazat.gov.hu/tamogatott_projektkereso?fbclid=IwAR3rmPVj-YAVoMTs2Vodj7JKTVIAZkbTiZ9z4b0j04mq2ThECw5kQOI1p7M")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group' and .//label[@for='programok']]//div[contains(@class,'css-1wy0on6')]"))).click()
```

Now you can select one of the presented options.
But again, this is not a `Select` element here.

Comment: Great! You are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, another problem emerged. How do you find the xpath for the element you want to select. I tried to save the html stuctufe of the page after the click, but I constantly fail to detect the value I want to pick. Thank you for the answer in advance

Comment: I guess this is another question? Please one a new question for it and I will try to help there as well. SO rules saying each question should be about one specific issue.

Comment: My current issue is that I found that css-26l3qy-menu css leads to the object, but I click on them, it chooses a random one. And on the console I only see the options if I click on the dropdown menu, but then I cannot inspect detailed the xpath code, thus I do not know how to specify which one I want to select.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you and I don't see elements matching `css-26l3qy-menu` there

Comment: I have created a new q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268339/find-xpath-after-opened-a-dropdown-menu-to-python-selenium